# DataGrid Binding checkbox data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed

xaml code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridCheckBox">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding stat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="UnCheckBox_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="_dataGrid" AllowDrag="False">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
        <xcdg:TableflowView FixedColumnCount="1" />
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>

    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="." Title="Select" Width="50" IsMainColumn="True"
                     CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource GridCheckBox}"            
                     GroupValueTemplate="{StaticResource GridCheckBox}"/>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

Filling a data to xceed datagrid

```
 DataGridCollectionView collectionView = new DataGridCollectionView(dt.DefaultView);
          collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new DataGridGroupDescription("filter"));
          _dataGrid.ItemsSource = collectionView;
```

All other details binding fine but not checkbox;Can anyone help me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to the previous answer you say that if stat=1 checkbox should be ticked. If `stat` is not a bool, you have to use a Converter so you can get bind to `IsChecked` property.

The converter should be simple as:

```
  public class StatConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value is int)
      {
        return (int)value == 1;
      }

      return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
  }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your IsChecked-Binding try to provide a `RelativeSource` to your `Window`/`UserConrolt` where your DataContext is.

The binding for the IsChecked-Property than looks something like:

```
IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.stat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
```

Comment: Nope..Still having same problem.

Comment: Take a look in the Output. Is there an Error4?

Comment: No errors!! if stat=1, checkbox should be ticked,but its not showing ticked.means data is not binding.